# Function call with more than 4 registers ARM assembly

Tags: function, assembly, stack, arm, gnu

I am trying to pass r0-r5 into the function `check`.  However only the registers r0-r3 are copied by reference. In my main function i have this code.

```
    push {lr}
    mov r0, #1
    mov r1, #2
    mov r2, #3
    mov r3, #4
    mov r4, #5
    mov r5, #6
    bl check
    pop {lr}
    bx lr
```

Inside my `check` function i have this code. This is in a separate file also not sure if that matters

```
    m: .asciz "%d, %d ~ (%d, %d, %d)
    ...
    push {lr}
    ldr r0, =m
    bl printf
    pop {lr}
    bx lr
```

The output for this is `2, 3 ~ (4, 33772, 1994545180)`. I am trying to learn assembly so can you please explain the answer with some googling i know i need to use the stack but, I am not sure how to use it and would like to learn how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be a bit of a tough read if you're not overly familiar with everything involved, but for reference you can find the official definition of the EABI calling convention [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

you could just try it and see

```
void check ( unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int );

void call_check ( void )
{
    check(1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -O2 check.c -o check.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D check.o

```
00000000 <call_check>:
   0:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e3a03005    mov r3, #5
   8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   c:   e58d3000    str r3, [sp]
  10:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
  14:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
  18:   e3a02003    mov r2, #3
  1c:   e3a03004    mov r3, #4
  20:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <check>
  24:   e28dd00c    add sp, sp, #12
  28:   e8bd8000    ldmfd   sp!, {pc}
```

now of course this could be hand optimized and still work just fine.  Maybe they are keeping the stack aligned on a 16 byte/4 word/64 bit boundary is the reason for the additional 12 byte modification to the stack pointer?  dont know. but other than that you can see that you naturally need to save the link register since you are calling another function.  r0 - r3 are obvious and then per the eabi the first thing on the stack is the 5th word worth of parameters.

Likewise for your check function you can simply let the compiler get you started.  If you look at your code, r0 is coming in as your first parameter and then you trash it by changing it to the first parameter for printf.  you need 6 parameters for printf to pass in. you need to move them over one the first parameter to check is the second parameter to printf, the second to check is third to printf and so on.  so the code has to do that shift (two of which now are on the stack).